Milo - idiomatic way of getting diagnostics (server, session & subscription)
I'm using Milo SDK 0.68 (via Kotlin) to ingest information about the OPC-UA server's diagnostics.
For the server summary diagnostics, for one node, I use this form of call:
opcUaClient.readValue(
            0.0,
            TimestampsToReturn.Source,
            nodeId
        ).get().value.value?.let { it as UInteger }

where nodeId can be for example Identifiers.Server_ServerDiagnostics_ServerDiagnosticsSummary_CurrentSessionCount.
My question is:
What is the idiomatic way of ingesting diagnostics and leveraging existing types inside the SDK?
Using the same logic for sessions will yield a null result, presumably because I am reading the wrong node.

I don't know anything about Milo SDK, but just a pure Kotlin suggestion: instead of value?.let { it as UInteger } you can write the shorter equivalent value as? UInteger.
